# Integrate buddyblog plugin to bbpress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I just installed buddyblog plugin in my buddypress site but when the user posts a blog there is like button but when the user's click on like it redirects to the wordpress login " but users of my site have already signed in to my buddypress site" can any 1 help me in integrating it with buddypress login so that users can like the posts after signing in to my bbpress site without going to wordpress login redirect .